# Cassandra "Detected unreadable sstables " Error

Tags: cassandra, startup, cassandra-2.0

On my windows box, after a graceful restart for windows update, I get the following error in Cassandra (2.2.0) and it will not start:

ERROR 10:36:41 Detected unreadable sstables D:\cassandra_data\data\gputptest-abcdedf-5040777060fe11e5a8557fcd8340170b-KeyCache-b.db,D:\cassandra_data\data\OpsCenter-events_timeline-afbbeee05cea11e59ba77fcd8340170b-KeyCache-b.db,D:\cassandra_data\data\system-IndexInfo-9f5c6374d48532299a0a5094af9ad1e3-KeyCache-b.db,...., please check NEWS.txt and ensure that you have upgraded through all required intermediate versions, running upgradesstables

Any suggestion how I can recover the database? Or, at least drop those unreadable sstables and recover the rest?

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved [Credit goes to Jeff Jirsa for his post [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201508.mbox/%3C58A8DD0A-AF3A-44C4-AA18-482202A6190D@crowdstrike.com%3E)]

I simply deleted all *.-KeyCache-b.db files reported in the error message. Then, I started Cassandra and everything was fine.

To delete the problematic *.-KeyCache-b.db files (there were 30 of them in the error message), I put the file names in a text file and ran the following command in powershell:

```
Get-Content unreadables_stables.txt | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thank you so much!