# Cassandra Detected unreadable sstables(data not caches)

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

> ERROR [main] 2017-08-04 13:24:21,949 CassandraDaemon.java:638 - Detected unreadable sstables /opt/cassandra/data/some_key_space/ep_lc_events-adc44160dbe611e6953689bcd3ed73aa/mc-547-big-Summary.db, and many others...

That has happened after I upgraded Cassandra to 3 version and after a while downgraded it to 2nd version.

When I run this command: `sudo service cassandra status`

I have got such message:

> could not access pidfile for Cassandra

In `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` I have logs which I wrote at the beginning.

PS: let me pay your attention that everything is happening on EC2 Amazon instance.

Comment: That does not work in my case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845713/cassandra-detected-unreadable-sstables-error

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You should double check - which user is cassandra running on? Whom are the sstables beloning. Did you issue and `nodetool upgradesstables`?

Comment: Can you try to delete the key caches (under saved caches in data dir) while node is off and restart? or is that what you mean by your "data not caches" bit?

Comment: @Mandraenke, cassandra is run by root user, sstables which are in /opt/cassandra/data are belong to cassandra.
What about `nodetool upgradesstables`... I have not tried it. Worth it to try?

Comment: @Mandraenke, `nodetool upgradesstables` does not work because it cannot connect to cassandra. Look how it was: when I downgrated cassandra back to 2 version I had to change `cassandra.yaml` in `/etc/cassandra/conf`, because it saw in `/var/lib/cassandra/data/` where there is no data, all my data in `/opt/cassandra/data`, so I changed the configuration in `cassandra.yaml` and dns to cassandra too, as it configured in Route 53. And it cannot see the data because of that ERROR.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink, thank you for reply. I will take it into account, but off the node I will try at the end of the all suggestions. Firstly want to try everything else what could help, besides off node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have just upgraded back to 3rd version, used `cassandra-unloader`  to export all data, then downgraded back to 2nd version and used `cassandra-loader` to import all data. But if you were lucky and had backups and snapshots it would not be an obstacle for you.

PS. Afterwards, I had to run this command `nodetool resetlocalschema` to reset local schema and resynchronize.

PPS. This you can find how to do that.
https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error, but it was due to switching between cassandra 4.0.0 and version 3.11 and back again while using docker.

#### Update the version to the right one for the ssltable, or delete the data volume:

```
docker-compose logs cassandra
docker volumes ls
docker ps
docker-compose down
docker volume rm testapp_cassandra
docker volume ls

docker-compose up
```