Cassandra won't run in AKS, getting "Detected unreadable sstables"
I am not able to run cassandra in azure kuberenetes services, i have made the service file and the statefulset yaml file as follows:
(base) bert:~$ kubectl get service cassandra -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"cassandra"},"name":"cassandra","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"clusterIP":"None","ports":[{"port":9042}],"selector":{"app":"cassandra"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-08-30T11:09:05Z"
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "13709044"
  uid: 9dc2efa0-6741-4dad-9ab0-904ab51c225a
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  clusterIPs:
  - None
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - port: 9042
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9042
  selector:
    app: cassandra
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}


and
(base) bert:~$ kubectl get statefulset cassandra -n default -o yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"StatefulSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"cassandra"},"name":"cassandra","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"replicas":1,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"cassandra"}},"serviceName":"cassandra","template":{"metadata":{"labels":{"app":"cassandra"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"env":[{"name":"MAX_HEAP_SIZE","value":"512M"},{"name":"HEAP_NEWSIZE","value":"100M"},{"name":"CASSANDRA_SEEDS","value":"cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"},{"name":"CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME","value":"K8Demo"},{"name":"CASSANDRA_DC","value":"DC1-K8Demo"},{"name":"CASSANDRA_RACK","value":"Rack1-K8Demo"},{"name":"POD_IP","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"status.podIP"}}}],"image":"gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13","imagePullPolicy":"Always","lifecycle":{"preStop":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/sh","-c","nodetool drain"]}}},"name":"cassandra","ports":[{"containerPort":7000,"name":"intra-node"},{"containerPort":7001,"name":"tls-intra-node"},{"containerPort":7199,"name":"jmx"},{"containerPort":9042,"name":"cql"}],"readinessProbe":{"exec":{"command":["/bin/bash","-c","/ready-probe.sh"]},"initialDelaySeconds":15,"timeoutSeconds":5},"resources":{"limits":{"cpu":"2000m","memory":"4Gi"},"requests":{"cpu":"1000m","memory":"2Gi"}},"securityContext":{"capabilities":{"add":["IPC_LOCK"]}},"volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/cassandra_data","name":"cassandra-data"}]}],"terminationGracePeriodSeconds":500}},"volumeClaimTemplates":[{"metadata":{"name":"cassandra-data"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"10Gi"}},"storageClassName":"fast"}}]}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-08-30T12:22:25Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: cassandra
  name: cassandra
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "13729005"
  uid: fbc72546-b52e-4654-a0f9-0d09fff8c89c
spec:
  persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy:
    whenDeleted: Retain
    whenScaled: Retain
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  serviceName: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
          value: 512M
        - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
          value: 100M
        - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
          value: cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
        - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
          value: K8Demo
        - name: CASSANDRA_DC
          value: DC1-K8Demo
        - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
          value: Rack1-K8Demo
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - nodetool drain
        name: cassandra
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7000
          name: intra-node
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 7001
          name: tls-intra-node
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 7199
          name: jmx
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9042
          name: cql
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /ready-probe.sh
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 4Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 2Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
            - IPC_LOCK
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /cassandra_data
          name: cassandra-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 500
  updateStrategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      partition: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
      storageClassName: fast
      volumeMode: Filesystem
    status:
      phase: Pending
status:
  availableReplicas: 0
  collisionCount: 0
  currentReplicas: 1
  currentRevision: cassandra-5ff88569c
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  updateRevision: cassandra-5ff88569c
  updatedReplicas: 1


here is my resource monitor : attached as image

my cassandra-0 pod goes to crashloopbackoff:
here are the cassandra logs errors:
detected unreadable sstables
i want to run cassandra on my cluster's nodepool and I am looking for a solution why is this happening.

does this post help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845713/cassandra-detected-unreadable-sstables-error

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

You haven't enough relevant information in your question but the issue you described indicates that there are SSTables on disk which are not compatible with the Cassandra binaries installed on the pod.
The error Detected unreadable sstables is thrown by the Cassandra process when it detects during startup that there is at least 1 file in the data directory with an incompatible format. This indicates that the mounted data/ volume is not empty and contains files from a previous installation of Cassandra.
As a side note, you need to provide more details in your question. The main things you need to add are (1) the full error message PLUS (2) the full stack trace, and (3) the Cassandra version.
A friendly reminder that you should provide sufficient information when asking questions to make it easier for contributors to help you. If you need guidance, see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specifically for Cassandra-related questions, I've published Asking good questions on the Apache Cassandra website. Cheers!
